# asp.net core 5 webapi error "Failed to determine the https port for redirect" for any ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value except Development

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I am running a .net core 5 web api in IIS.  My web config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <!--<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>-->
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DemoService.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development"/>
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have appsettings.config, appsettings.Development.config and appsettings.Test Config.  When I deploy to my server,  if I set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable in my web.config to "Developent" it all works fine.  If I set it to "Test" I get a 404 and the following error in the event log:

> Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware
> EventId: 3 SpanId: 6854a856fbbd6a42 TraceId:
> 9cb7b4e2bb5dcf4f9b63af3741021379 ParentId: 0000000000000000 RequestId:
> 80000054-0001-a200-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath:
> /Dir/SubDir/WebAPI/swagger/index.html
>
> Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

Are there constraints on the value set that ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT can be, or additional configuration I need to have for each possible value I might specify?

I've been able to recreate this on my dev box and trace through all code in startup.cs, no exceptions are thrown.  Totally mind boggled here.

I have corresponding appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, and appsettings.Test.json files which look as follows:

```
{
  "Logging":
  {
    "LogLevel":
    {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationSettings":
  {
    "Environment": "Local Dev",
    "ExceptionHandling":
    {
      "UseDeveloperExceptionPage": false,
      "ShowExceptionDetail": true
    },
    "ConnectionStrings":
    {
      "Registry": "...;"
    }
  }
}

{
  "Logging":
  {
    "LogLevel":
    {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationSettings":
  {
    "Environment": "Dev",
    "ExceptionHandling":
    {
      "UseDeveloperExceptionPage": false,
      "ShowExceptionDetail": true
    },
    "ConnectionStrings":
    {
      "Registry": "..."
    }
  }
}

{
  "Logging":
  {
    "LogLevel":
    {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationSettings":
  {
    "Environment": "Test",
    "ExceptionHandling":
    {
      "UseDeveloperExceptionPage": true,
      "ShowExceptionDetail": true
    },
    "ConnectionStrings":
    {
      "Registry": "...;"
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Get our custom configuration for the application
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<State.ApplicationSettings>();

        //Set up dependency injection
        //IServiceCollection.AddSingleton - creates a single instance throughout the application. It creates the instance for the first time and reuses the same object in the all calls.
        //IServiceCollection.AddScoped - services are created once per request within the scope. It is equivalent to a singleton in the current scope. For example, in MVC it creates one instance for each HTTP request, but it uses the same instance in the other calls within the same web request.
        //IServiceCollection.AddTransient -  services are created each time they are requested. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.

        services.AddSingleton<State.ApplicationSettings>(appSettingsSection.Get<State.ApplicationSettings>());

        services.AddScoped<IRegistryLookup>((svc) =>
        {
            return new RegistryLookup(appSettings.ConnectionStrings.Registry);
        });

        services.AddControllers()
            //.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
            .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
            .AddJsonOptions(o =>
            {
                o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
            });


        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = $"My Service ({appSettings.Environment})", Version = "v1" });
            c.ExampleFilters();
        });

        services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<Startup>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, State.ApplicationSettings settings)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DemoService v1"));
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "DemoService v1"));
        }
   
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }        
}
```

Comment: If possible, you can share the code of your `startup.cs`, we will help check it.

Comment: @FeiHan - startup code added.